# Arithmetic operation and for loop in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

As the title says, I am trying to use arithmetic operations and for loop in terminal but keep getting an error message.

```
for ((i=0; i<=10000; i++)); do ns part1.tcl Reno Reno $(($i * 0.001)) ${i}.tr; done
```

And the error message is:
bash: 0 * 0.001 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "0.001 ")

How can I fix it?

Comment: `bash` doesn't have floating point numbers, it only supports integers.

Comment: @Barmar is correct, you'll have to do floating point math through `bc` or some other utility